# Should we create a site to help teachers with classroom technology?

Tags: discussion

> This is [a cross post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1950/254). It should have dawned on me to ask here all along! Curious of your thoughts.

I'm Sam and I work at Stack <strike>Exchange</strike> Overflow. I come here before you because I'm not sure where else on the network to go! There isn't a Stack Exchange site for K-12 teachers, and I think they could benefit massively from one.

I think this because I live with a teacher and I see day and night how tirelessly she works. I see how little support from colleagues she receives. Unlike a lot of jobs (like mine), when she's in the heat of battle, she can't ask for reinforcements. Her job is so. damn. hard.

To make her job a little easier she's begun to implement Google Classroom at her school. After a couple weeks, it's showing promising returns. She's making fewer trips to the photocopier. Grading is easier. Students are engaging more.

But a lack of teacher-focused documentation almost led her not to adopt it. Outdated how-to's made implementation more difficult than it ever should have been.

This is a problem I think maybe we can solve, and that's why I created a site proposal:

**[Classroom Tech](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/90679/classroom-tech?referrer=p6Sj9uYUMG7oXm3CuwYaPg2)**

I don't know if the site is scoped right. I don't know if it will work. A couple weeks ago I tweeted at a prominent Google Classroom advocate asking for her opinion. [She said](https://twitter.com/alicekeeler/status/641625665784180736):

> most T's don't use stacks.

I think maybe that's true because we don't have one yet. Curious what you think.

Comment: I recommend absolute, crystal clarity.  There are a lot of situations where a teacher may have computer access outside of class, but none inside.  Before someone enters the site, they should be clear on what "Classroom Tech" means.  If it is purely computer oriented, there are a lot who won't/can't use it.  If it contains answers on what to do in the absence of such resources, you might have something.  Check online for other teaching resources (e.g. RAFT) to see what is missing that the site could provide.  Gerhard "Sounds Like An Exciting Proposal" Paseman, 2015.09.28

Comment: Also, if you are willing to confront reality (and persevere in spite of it), a lot of the opinions you want will come from low to mid level school administrators too.  They may have the key idea or problem your site is really supposed to solve, and you can build it to solve that, initially.  Gerhard "That's What I Call Marketing" Paseman, 2015.09.28

Comment: I think the scope you mention is too narrow to succeed as a Stack Exchange site.  Perhaps a more general site (such as this [Educators](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82415/educators?referrer=_SfkmmVQxL-sTX8MSqhB0g2) proposal) would be more successful.

Answer (score 1):

I look at the discussions regarding 'graduation,' noting the level of activity required for a site to be considered healthy, and worthy of being graduated to full site status.

ME.SE is still beta, and so far, this topic appears to have just minor interest. A few questions out of thousands. Even after expanding to non-math classes, I don't see there being enough discussion to have a successful stack with such a limited topic.